# How to build a method with unspecified amount of params en C#

Tags: c#, parameters

This is my code:

```
    private static string AddURISlash(string remotePath)
    {
        if (remotePath.LastIndexOf("/") != remotePath.Length - 1)
        {
            remotePath += "/";
        }
        return remotePath;
    }
```

But I need something like

```
AddURISlash("http://foo", "bar", "baz/", "qux", "etc/");
```

If I recall correctly, string.format is somehow like that...

```
String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3} at {4}", 255, 255, 255, 0, "4 p.m.");
```

Is there something in C# that allows me to do so?

I know I could do

```
private static string AddURISlash(string[] remotePath)
```

but that's not the idea.

If this is something in some framework can be done and in others not please specify and how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use params, which lets you specify any amount of arguments

```
private static string AddURISlash(params string[] remotePaths)
{
    foreach (string path in remotePaths)
    {
        //do something with path
    }
}
```

Note that `params` will impact the performance of your code, so use it sparingly.

Comment: Would this allow me both writing formats (array and parameters) or should I overload? Does params keyword exist in 1.1?

Comment: You should be able to use params in 1.1 without any problem. :)

Comment: @Msonic "not string arrays" -> to call `AddURISlash(new string[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" });` is valid for this signature

Answer (score 6):

I think you want a [*parameter array*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx):

```
private static string CreateUriFromSegments(params string[] segments)
```

Then you *implement* it knowing that `remotePath` is just an array, but you can *call* it with:

```
string x = CreateUriFromSegments("http://foo.bar", "x", "y/", "z");
```

(As noted in comments, a parameter array can only appear as the last parameter in a declaration.)

Comment: It's also important to mention that it has to be the last parameter in the method signature.

Comment: Would this allow me both writing formats or should I overload? Does params keyword exist in 1.1? CreateUriFromSegments and UriFromSegments mean the same function?

Comment: @apacay Why are you using 1.1?

Comment: I've been with C# for a while and never knew of that functionality. Thanks.

Comment: @Scott Enterprise restrictions. In some cases I'm only allowed to use either 1.1, 2.0 or 3.5

Comment: @apacay: I assume you're talking about .NET versions? C# versions are somewhat different. But yes, `params` has been in C# since 1.0. When you *are* restricted to C# 1, it's worth including that in the question as it's such a rare requirement these days. (And yes, I meant to use the same name twice. I felt that `AddURISlash` didn't cover what was going on here.)

Comment: I'll do that next time, my mistake. *If this is something in some framework can be done and in others not please specify and how to resolve it.* Since I work with this diversity, I thought that message would be enough.

Comment: @apacay: It's not really clear what you meant - I suspected you meant in some other library. If you meant "If this is only available in later versions of .NET or C#" then that's what you should have said. "In some framework" is hopelessly vague. Explicitly stating that you're working in C# 1 would have been most helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry then. I'll improve that next time. English isn't my native language.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
private static string AddURISlash(params string[] remotePath)
```

That will allow you to pass a `string[]` as a number of separate parameters.

Answer (score 3):

This might be what you're looking for (note the `params` keyword):

```
private static string AddURISlash(params string[] remotePath) {
    // ...
}
```