# Methods: params string[] with one parameter and single string

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

This comes from this other question:
( [How to build a method with unspecified amount of params en C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9487724/684646) ).
But since it's a different question I had to ask it here

Supposing you have a method overloaded (this overload is allowed by the compiler):

```
private static string AddURISlash(params string[] remotePaths) //multiple strings
private static string AddURISlash(string remotePaths) //single string
```

How should you know which will be executed when only one parameter is recieved?

Is there a convention? or something that you have to test once?
Do I have to assume that since the only way to the *single string* method to be executed is *to recieve a single string*, that's the one that unequivocally be executed?

Thanks

Comment: Why even have the second option? Unless the semantics are different, but then in that case it would be better to name them differently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How should you know which will be executed when only one parameter is recieved?

You read the specification, which explains how overload resolution is handled. From section 7.5.3.2, the relevant bullet point is:

> Otherwise, if M<sub>P</sub> is applicable in its normal form and M<sub>Q</sub> has a params array and is applicable only in its expanded form, then M<sub>P</sub> is better than M<sub>Q</sub>.

So the version which *doesn't* require parameter array expansion (your single string version) is chosen at compile-time instead of the parameter array version.